# WPF: Cursor is displayed in any of the fields after executing search (Enter) but after user is not able to delete the searchable field value

Tags: c#, wpf, search, cursor, focus

I have a **form** with several textbox elements and one search button. After adding criteria, when i press Enter key, i get results in datagrid. Button has IsDefault property set to true (default button).

What happens is actually that **Cursor is displayed in the field(textbox) when user successfully searches for the elements with any of the searchable fields**.

And User can view the cursor **but user is not able to delete the searchable field values after the search is successful or failure**. (After pressing Enter key)

How to keep focus on element(**if cursor is there, does it mean its already focused ?**) after executing search result with Enter key, a**nd be able to delete field with (Backspace)** keyboard or edit.

Comment: I fear this question will be heavily downvoted or even closed. I am not fluent in WPF but I strongly suggest to post [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).